# How can I update PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST for my process?

Tags: c++, security, winapi, windows-10

Say, when my process was created using [`STARTUPINFOEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/WinBase/ns-winbase-_startupinfoexa) struct and the `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST` member:

```
DWORD ProtectionLevel = PROTECTION_LEVEL_SAME;
SIZE_T AttributeListSize;
STARTUPINFOEXW StartupInfoEx = { 0 };


StartupInfoEx.StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(StartupInfoEx);


InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(NULL, 1, 0, &AttributeListSize)


StartupInfoEx.lpAttributeList = (LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST) HeapAlloc(
GetProcessHeap(),
0,
AttributeListSize
);


if (InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(StartupInfoEx.lpAttributeList,
1,
0,
&AttributeListSize) == FALSE)
{
Result = GetLastError();
goto exitFunc;
}


if (UpdateProcThreadAttribute(StartupInfoEx.lpAttributeList,
0,
PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PROTECTION_LEVEL,
&ProtectionLevel,
sizeof(ProtectionLevel),
NULL,
NULL) == FALSE)
{
Result = GetLastError();
goto exitFunc;
}


PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation = { 0 };


if (CreateProcessW(ApplicationName,
CommandLine,
ProcessAttributes,
ThreadAttributes,
InheritHandles,
EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT | CREATE_PROTECTED_PROCESS,
Environment,
CurrentDirectory,
(LPSTARTUPINFOW)&StartupInfoEx,
&ProcessInformation) == FALSE)
{
Result = GetLastError();
goto exitFunc;
}
```

How can I update that attribute list for my own process?

For instance, I want to modify my own process' [`PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_CHILD_PROCESS_POLICY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-updateprocthreadattribute) to prevent it from creating any child processes.

Comment: "*How can I update that attribute list for my own process?*" - AFAIK, you can't. "*I want to ... prevent [my process] from creating any child processes.*" - then simply don't call functions that spawn child processes. You don't need to modify your process policies to accomplish that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Funny. It's the attack mitigation attempt. Say when a buffer overflow (in my process) is used to launch a shell code from the vuln process.

Comment: It wasn't meant to be funny. I don't know what a "vuln process" is, but have you considered simply hooking `CreateProcess()` to block it from starting a new process? On the other hand, you shouldn't be allocating buffers that can be used to execute arbitrary code in the first place, unless it is  shell code of your own intention. The Win32 API provides protections for ensuring memory buffers are not executable memory (DEP, etc), use them.

Comment: Sorry. It was supposed to be `vulnerable process`.

Comment: and yes, only if we all knew where our buffer overflow 0-days will be coming from ... oh those [glorious days of precogs](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181689/?ref_=nv_sr_1) to come.

Comment: in `struct TOKEN` exist field `ULONG TokenFlags;` when you set `PROCESS_CREATION_CHILD_PROCESS_RESTRICTED` the `0x80000` added to `TokenFlags`. the add this by another way - i not view how. however remove is possible - if you have `SeTcbPrivilege` - you can call `SetTokenInformation` with `TokenChildProcessFlags` with `DWORD flags = 0` - this remove `0x80000` flag. exactly `0x80000` flag prevent process from create child

Comment: @RbMm: Thanks. I need to try it. I'm assuming it's pretty much undocumented, hah? I needed to do this from the `system` service anyway, so `TCB` privilege is available. I'm curious when Microsoft introduced that `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_CHILD_PROCESS_POLICY` option, how did they want us to set it for a local service?

Comment: you can **only remove** this flag by call `ULONG flags = 0; SetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenChildProcessFlags, &flags, sizeof(flags))` in case you have `SeTcbPrivilege`. no option for set. undocumented

Comment: @RbMm: yeah, it's understandable that the process should not be able to allow itself to create children processes (from the user mode code) if that option was first disabled. Makes total sense from a security standpoint. That's pretty much how most of those mitigation policies work.

Comment: You know what's funny (in a sick kinda way) is that it seems like whoever drew a short straw at Microsoft to document all those things, kinda ran out of juice by the [end of this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ne-winnt-token_information_class) :)

Comment: what i write - simply research in debugger - i create process with `PROCESS_CREATION_CHILD_PROCESS_RESTRICTED` and without it. and compare tokens. only different in `TokenFlags` - `0x82000` vs `0x2000`. also i look for `NtSetInformationToken` with `TokenChildProcessFlags` - it can remove `0x80000` but never set

Comment: @RbMm: no, I appreciate you doing it. I wish I thought of this too. It's only because of researchers like yourself we're learning all this stuff (that really should've been documented.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185974/discussion-between-rbmm-and-c00000fd).

Comment: What if you add yourself to a job you create?

Comment: @Anders: It's a good thought. Although how do I assign `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST` to a job object?

Comment: @RbMm: you know, I can't even read that `TokenChildProcessFlags` value. `GetTokenInformation()` always fails when used with `TokenChildProcessFlags` with error code `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. The token comes from `OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);`

Comment: @c00000fd - but `TokenChildProcessFlags` is write only information class. you can set it , but can not read

Comment: @RbMm: Oh shoot. so there's no way to know if `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_CHILD_PROCESS_POLICY` is enabled for my process, hah?

Comment: for this you need read [`TOKEN.TokenFlags`](https://pastebin.com/rN3G1QH2) for your process. concrete `0x80000` flag in current win10 implementations. i not view any api/query which let do this. `TokenChildProcessFlags` not let read this. it allow only **reset** this flag. you can not set another flags, you can not even **set** this flag via `SetInformationToken` with `TokenChildProcessFlags`. you can only **reset** it in case it already set and you have *TCB* privileges

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, I saw your code in PasteBin. It works for a system service, but now I'm trying to see if I can reset that flag for my user-mode (non-admin) process. My hope was that if I can read the state of that flag for my process I can then restart self using `CreateProcess` and the `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_CHILD_PROCESS_POLICY` setting in the `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST`. But it gets kinda tricky if I can't know that setting.

Comment: *It works for a system service* - for admin app also work (i test it from usual app). but this is simply show ability reset this restriction when we know that it exist. *I can then restart self using CreateProcess* - you can not :) `CreateProcess` will fail

Comment: so if you have just tcb or if have debug privilege - you can got tcb (from system process). you can reset this restriction for self process. if no privileges - can not reset. restart self without reset this flag you can not

Comment: @RbMm: I'm probably not explaining myself correctly. What I want to do is to make sure that my own process _cannot create children processes_. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @c00000fd - if the `ERROR_CHILD_PROCESS_BLOCKED` returned by call `GetLastError()` after `CreateProcess` fail - you have this restriction. simply check error code

Comment: @c00000fd Jobs has nothing to do with thread attributes but you can get a callback when a new process is about to start or simply set a process limit of 1.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer my question entirely. It's a follow-up to the comments thread for my original post above.

So just for disabling creation of child processes (similar to `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_CHILD_PROCESS_POLICY`) one can enable this feature for their own process as such:

```
DWORD dwNoChild = 1;
BOOL bResult = ::SetProcessMitigationPolicy((PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY)13 /*ProcessChildProcessPolicy*/, 
    &dwNoChild, sizeof(dwNoChild));
```

Note that your process doesn't have to be elevated for this to work.

(Don't hold me to it, but I think that `ProcessChildProcessPolicy` flag is supported on Windows 10 only.)